# How to play back AudioRecord with some delay

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I'm implementing an app which will repeat everything I'm telling it.
What I need is to play the sound I'm recording on a buffer just with a second of delay
So that I would be listening myself but 1 second delayed

This is my run method of the Recorder class

```
public void run()
    {           
        AudioRecord recorder = null;
        int ix = 0;
        buffers = new byte[256][160];

        try
        {
            int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10);               
            recorder.startRecording();
            Timer t = new Timer();              
            SeekBar barra = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.barraDelay);
            t.schedule(r = new Reproductor(), barra.getProgress());           

            while(!stopped)
            {                   
                byte[] buffer = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];                 
                N = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);                  
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable x)
        {               
        }

        finally
        { 
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;                        
        }
```

And this is the run one of my player:

```
public void run() {
        reproducir = true;

        AudioTrack track = null;            
        int jx = 0;

        try
        {
            int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);               
            track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);              
            track.play();
            /*
             * Loops until something outside of this thread stops it.
             * Reads the data from the recorder and writes it to the audio track for playback.
             */
            while(reproducir)
            {                   
                byte[] buffer = buffers[jx++ % buffers.length];                 
                track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable x)
        {               
        }
        /*
         * Frees the thread's resources after the loop completes so that it can be run again
         */
        finally
        {               
            track.stop();
            track.release();
            track = null;               
        }

    }
```

Reproductor is an inner class extending TimerTask and implementing the "run" method.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can contact the author of [Idiotizer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nidrico.apps.idiotizerfree), it does what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

At least you should change the following line of your player

```
int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

to

```
int N = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

because the API requires that (albeit the constant values are identical).

But this is only a marginal point. The main point is that you did not really present an approach to your problem, but only two generic methods.

The core of a working solution is that you use a ring buffer with a size of 1s and `AudioTrack` reading a block of it just ahead of writing new data via `AudioRecord` to the same block, both at the same sample rate.

I would suggest to do that inside a single thread.